# Unable to locate the element inside the webview Appium

Tags: android, selenium-chromedriver, appium, android-webview, webdriver-io

I'm currently working on automating a hybrid app using Appium WebDriverIO. My script successfully switches to the webview context without any issues. However, I'm facing a problem when trying to locate an element inside the webview using XPath: `//input[@data-testing-id='name-input']`.

I've verified that the XPath is correct by inspecting the webview using `chrome://inspect/#devices`, where the element is present.

Error

```
[0-0] 2023-09-07T09:04:40.093Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
[0-0]   error: 'no such element',
[0-0]   message: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@data-testing-id='name-input']"}\n` +
[0-0]     '  (Session info: webview=116.0.0.0)',
[0-0]   stacktrace: '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C7CB52A2+57122]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7C2EA92]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7AFE3AB]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B37D3E]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B37E2C]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B70B67]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B5701F]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B6EB82]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B56DB3]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B2D2B1]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7B2E494]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C7F5EF82+2849794]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C7FB1D24+3189156]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C7FAACAF+3160367]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6C7D46D06+653702]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7C3A208]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7C362C4]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7C363F6]\n' +
[0-0]     '\t(No symbol) [0x00007FF6C7C267A3]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF9F65226BD+29]\n' +
[0-0]     '\tRtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9F6B6DFB8+40]\n'
[0-0] }
```

[Appium Logs Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qJggJun9yUKJcDMQVJZq_gbvNwe98w-K/view?usp=sharing)

Appium Version : 1.20.2

Chrome Version : 116.0.5845.164

Chromedriver Version : 116.0.5845.96

1. Verified Context Switching: I've made sure to correctly switch to the webview context.
2. Specified ChromeDriver Path:
   Appium was unable to get ChromeDriver version 116 automatically. To address this, I specified the ChromeDriver executable path inside the capabilities using the `chromedriverExecutable` capability
3. Tried Upgrading appium-chromedriver:
   In an attempt to resolve the issue, I upgraded the appium-chromedriver package to its latest version. However, the problem persisted.

Any further guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you still could not find element, try with CSS-Selector.

Answer (score 0):

After you switch to web view try to get all elements and check them, maybe you got some restrictions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).